# What does QueryDSL's PathBuilder's validate() do?

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl

QueryDSL documentation is unfortunately quite lacking. For many of the methods I've had to either dig deep into grepcode or to track down any source code online that uses the methods of interest to try to figure out how they're using it.

So what does QueryDSL's PathBuilder's validate() do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PathBuilder` provides a pluggable validation mechanism for property creation. You can inject a `PathBuilderValidator` via the constructor. The default validator passes every property.

In action this means that `pathBuilder.get("name")` will have `Object` by default, `String` for a String typed field using `PathBuilderValidator.FIELDS` and `String` for a String typed property using `PathBuilderValidator.PROPERTIES`.

Apologies for the limited documentation. That will be improved with the 4.0.0 release.

https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/e4b20fc15a6b6d8108ccfdf5cb22df47f929e5e7/querydsl-core/src/main/java/com/querydsl/core/types/path/PathBuilderValidator.java

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by property creation? Thanks!

Comment: How does one use PathValidator? It's QueryDSL 5.0 and I can only see two lines in the documentation on it- 'For PathBuilder validation a PathBuilderValidator can be used. It can be injected in the constructor and will be used transitively for the new PathBuilder

PathBuilder<Customer> customer = new PathBuilder<Customer>(Customer.class, "customer", validator);
PathBuilderValidator.FIELDS will verify field existence, PathBuilderValidator.PROPERTIES validates Bean properties and JPAPathBuilderValidator validates using a JPA metamodel.'